# NSolve Issues with Gamma and Incomplete Gamma

Tags: equation-solving

I'm not having any luck finding a solution to the following problem:

```
Assuming[{Re[\[Alpha] > 0] && Re[\[Beta] > 0]}, 
 NSolve[{(1 - Gamma[\[Beta], \[Alpha]/700]/Gamma[\[Beta]]) - 77/100 ==
     0, (1 - Gamma[\[Beta], \[Alpha]/1000]/Gamma[\[Beta]]) - 1/2 == 
    0}, {\[Alpha], \[Beta]}]]
```

I am able to manually finding a solution by looking at the intersection of the contour plots of the two equations, but I am looking for a direct numerical method.

Comment: Use FindRoot. Also, NSolve doesn't take advantage of $Assumptions, so using Assuming doesn't help.

Comment: `FindRoot` evaluates to `{α -> 3746.0401, β -> 4.0740856}`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks